# How to position an element to the LEFT of an other element?

Tags: css, layout

What is the idiomatic way to position an element (`X`) to the **left** of an other element (`inline-box 2`), independent of its size, using standard CSS & HTML?

[image]

It is okay if it appears over other elements.

Comment: Trickier than it looks, you would definitely need to take it out of the normal document flow using `absolute` positioning - that's easy enough, but to position it as intended would suggest that you would need to declare `left` and `top` (for example) relevant to a parent element. I'm loathe to use any negative values as quick, dirty "hacks", but in this case it may be called for.

Comment: Please check this https://fiddle.jshell.net/aj9v595p/ or https://fiddle.jshell.net/aj9v595p/1/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks for the tip, a negative `left` value comes closest so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution: to position an element to the **left** of another one, no matter their sizes, make it its child, and then *absolute*-position it **`right: 100%`**.

`100%` means the width of its parent, so 100% from the **right** will put it just ***left*** of it!

Using `left: -100%` wouldn't work, because it means: offset the **left** of the element *left* of the parent by the parent's width, however we want to offset by the width of the child element, itself.

CSS-only demo:

```css
/* The important parts */
#box2 {
  position: relative;
}
#x {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
  top: -1px;
}

/* Just styling */
#box1, #box2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#x {
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box1">box1</div>
  <div id="box2">box2
    <div id="x">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `left:0;transform:translateX(-100%)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, didn't think of that. So `right: 100%` (or `left`, etc) means 100% of the *parent*, but `translateX(100%)` means 100% of the element *itself*. Mind boggling